# unity Best Fit установить скриптом

Tags: unity3d

Не могу через скрипт установить значение Best Fit у текста - пробовал и у компонента Текст, и у объекта:

```
FontData.bestFit = true;
```

Пробовал и так:

```
FontData.bestFit(true);
```

Пробовал и без `FontData`, и с ним, но все равно что то не так. Как быть?

Comment: А как вы определили, что это не работает? Без ошибки сложно понять, где проблема.

Comment: Сорян, что долго не отвечал. Вот такая ошибка постоянно выскакивает:

 'Text' does not contain a definition for 'FontData' and no accessible extension method 'FontData' accepting a first argument of type 'Text' could be found , 

и если не использовать FontData, он пишет про bestFit то же самое на любом текстовом объекте, к которому применяю данный параметр

Comment: А причем здесь вообще `Text`, вы про него ни слова в вопросе не написали.

Comment: А, ну это просто компонент текста, который у моего текста висит

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос **всю** информацию, что где висит, как это на сцене расположено и инспектор самого текста.